# Stop mysql value from duplicate in php oop?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm generating questions from MYSQL into a loop. I would like for the question_category not to duplicate on every row, just displayed once on top of first question in that category?

Right now:
Question category 1 Question1   (O) (O) (O)
Question category 1 Question2   (O) (O) (O)
Question category 2 Question1   (O) (O) (O)
Question category 2 Question2   (O) (O) (O)

My goal:
Question category 1 
Question1   (O) (O) (O)
Question2   (O) (O) (O)
Question category2 
Question1   (O) (O) (O)
Question2   (O) (O) (O)

```
<?php
// generate active questions from DB
$query = "SELECT * FROM questions where active=1 AND question_sort=1 ORDER BY sort_by";
$result = @mysqli_query($con, $query);
?>
<div class="questions-1">  
    <table width="auto" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="answer_value">0</td>
            <td class="answer_value">1fta</td>
            <td class="answer_value">2</td>
          </tr>
<?php
if ($result) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    // question body for each question
    $body = $row['question_body'];
    // question id for each question
    $question_id = $row['question_id'];
    // question category for each question
    $question_category = $row['question_category'];
          echo '<tr>
            <td class="question">'.$question_category.'</td>
            <td class="question">'.$body.'</td>
            <td class="answer"><input type="radio" name="answer_value['.$question_id.']" value="0" ></td>
            <td class="answer"><input type="radio" name="answer_value['.$question_id.']" value="1" ></td>
            <td class="answer"><input type="radio" name="answer_value['.$question_id.']" value="2" ></td>
          </tr>';
}
?>
</table></div>
```

Comment: So check if it's the same and if so - don't output it.

Comment: Build some of this HTML by hand, get it to look the way you want. Then you'll see how you have to build the code to produce that html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your query apparently returns things already ordered so that all questions of a specific category are grouped together....

```
<?php
$currcategory = ""; // Holder to keep track of the current category we are working with.
if ($result) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    // question body for each question
    $body = $row['question_body'];
    // question id for each question
    $question_id = $row['question_id'];
    // question category for each question
    $question_category = $row['question_category'];
    if ($currcategory !== $question_category) { // The category has changed so lets create a 'header' row.
        $currcatgory = $question_category;
        echo '<tr><td colspan="5">'.$currcategory.'</td></tr>';
    }
          echo '<tr>
            <td class="question">'.$question_category.'</td>
            <td class="question">'.$body.'</td>
            <td class="answer"><input type="radio" name="answer_value['.$question_id.']" value="0" ></td>
            <td class="answer"><input type="radio" name="answer_value['.$question_id.']" value="1" ></td>
            <td class="answer"><input type="radio" name="answer_value['.$question_id.']" value="2" ></td>
          </tr>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a query `"SELECT DISTINCT question_category FROM questions"` and in that loop do your `"SELECT * FROM questions where active=1 AND question_category='$row->question_category' AND question_sort=1 ORDER BY sort_by"` query

Comment: The issue is that you are introducing a O(n^2) solution. Since the query is a potential network call, this is just a bad habit to get into. It's better to make sure the database has already ordered your data appropriately and keep track of the category yourself.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be

```
$cur_question_category = '';

Then in your loop, if($question_category != $cur_question_category) { 
// display the category
}
else
{
//do not display the category
}
$cur_question_category=$question_category;
...
```

This assumes of course your query is ordering by question_category at some stage in the order by